# jtds driver query has times out

Tags: sql-server, jtds

I am getting this error frequently (not always) running against SQL server with no reason why it should be the case. 
The query just runs fine otherwise and is very quick.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The query has timed out.
>               at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.wait(TdsCore.java:4024)
>   ~[jtds-1.2.8.jar:1.2.8]

Are there any knows issues with this and how to overcome this problem. let me know if any other detail will help to answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is nothing but you have forgot commit your last executed statement.